# How do I calculate this limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{ 1-x^n}{1-x^m}$?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I'm having problem finding limit of lim $x \to 1$ for $(1-x^n)/(1-x^m$). I know that the result is $n/m$ but I can't really come up with how to modify the expression to arrive at that.

Comment: Hint:  both numerator and denominator are divisible by $1-x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n,m\in\mathbb N$, then

$$1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1})$$

Thus, your ratio reduces to

$$\frac{1-x^n}{1-x^m}=\frac{1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1}}{1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{m-1}}\stackrel{x\to1}\longrightarrow\frac nm$$

Comment: How in the name of Jesus do you type in latex that fast?

Comment: @mrnovice Copy + paste

Comment: Well played, +1

Comment: I didn't come even close to thinking of geometric series. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ZergOvermind no problem!  Glad to help :-)